# Try to do something vs. Try doing something

Tags: grammar, differences

Is there any differences between

> Try to do

And

> Try doing

Thank you in advence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Try to do*** is an effort to do something which you already know.

*For example.*

I tried to open the door.

I tried to call her.

***Try doing*** is an effort based on more of a guess work.

*For example.*

Try hitting it with hammer, it might come off.

**[An elaborate post here.](https://www.englishforums.com/English/TryToDoAndTryDoing/hjbkr/post.htm)**

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary.com's first 2 definitions of 'try' are:

> 1. to attempt to do or accomplish:
> 2. to test the effect or result of

To my (British English) ear, 'try to do' implies usage of the first meaning here, whereas 'try doing' implies the second.

Answer (score 2):

"do" has different meanings.  One is like "achieve something" and another is like "perform an action".

Both "try to do" and "try doing" could mean either of these, but "try to do" has a stronger connotation of the "achieve" meaning and "try doing" has a stronger connotation of the "perform an action" meaning.